# WPF adding rows to a DataGrid via the grid itself

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am just wondering if its possible to add rows to a datagrid (so to a ObservableCollection to the object model) via the grid itself?

I don't particularly want to be use a new view to do this (though wouldnt be the end of the world if I did)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`DataGrid.CanUserAddRows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.canuseraddrows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

> When this property is set to true a blank row is displayed at the bottom of the `DataGrid`. A user can enter a new item into the blank row. Adding a new row adds an item to the ItemsSource. You can set default values for the new item by handling the `InitializingNewItem` event and setting the values programmatically.

Example:

```
<DataGrid Name="MyDataGrid" 
          CanUserAddRows="True" ... />
```

Comment: One more thing, if the ItemSource is empty or NULL on load, no default row appears. I am guessing I need to initalise the collection so a row appears?

Comment: @user3428422: I believe that yes, because (quote from MSDN): `Adding a new row adds an item to the ItemsSource.`.

Comment: Thanks finally, when a new row does appear, all of the item source properties are bounded to the grid, however, I have written Datagrid.columns of the columns I only want to show, is there a property I need to use to only show the columns that I have specified?

Comment: @user3428422: I do not understand the question, you want to set for visibility of some columns? For the future, if there is a new question, `please create a new question`, but do not write it in the comments.

Comment: Ok will do. Not exactly, the grid has all the properties that the model contains, but I dont want all of the properties that the model contains, only a set few. I have code  <DataGrid.Columns> of the columns (properties) that I want to show in the grid, but all of them are still being shown..

Comment: @user3428422: Ok, create a new question, because I can not understand everything from the comments.